# What is happening in the few seconds surrounding t=0 of the Delta IV Heavy launch?

Tags: launch, rockets, launch-sequence, delta-iv-heavy

Watching footage of the Orion test launch on Dec 5th, one can see orange flames rise up from the base of the rocket in the few seconds before t=0 and before the engines appear to fully "fire up".

Nothing like it is visible on Space Shuttle launch footage.

What is happening in the launch sequence to produce these effects?

A description of the Saturn V mentions that ignition was accomplished by "bursting a hypergolic cartridge". Does the Delta IV heavy do something similar?

Comment: Related: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3241/why-not-use-sparklers-on-delta-4-heavy-launches-to-burn-off-the-hydrogen .

Comment: @DavidHammen after reading the question & answer you cite, I flagged this as a duplicate.